# How to select lines from a pandas dataset based on a regex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

indexes = [1, 7, 12, 13, 21]
strings = ["a1", "y1", "n1", "d2", "s3"]
doubles = [1.2, 23.09, 6.034, 3.91, 5.2]
d = {"strings": strings, "doubles": doubles}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=indexes)
```

So this creates pandas DataFrame:

```
   doubles strings
1  1.200   'a1'
7  23.090  'y1'
12 6.034   'n1'
13 3.910   'd2'
27 5.2     's3'
```

I want to select lines from this DataFrame based on a regex applied on the 'string' column. So far I found a solution:

```
df[df.strings.str.findall('[0-2]$').str.len() > 0]
```

My question is: is there a more elegant way to do this? 
I tried

```
df[df.strings.filter('[0-2]$') ...]
```

but I got only errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and use the same regex pattern:

```
In [111]:
df[df['strings'].str.contains('[0-2]$', regex=True)]

Out[111]:
    doubles strings
1     1.200      a1
7    23.090      y1
12    6.034      n1
13    3.910      d2
```